# jenkins build and deploy to artifactory

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jenkins-job-dsl

I am building using jenkins slave machine, doing free style jobs, 
I use Build step as execute shell sh script.sh

My problem is, I have built build 1 already, and after the build line sh script.sh I didn't used curl command to deploy to Artifactory.
Now, if I add curl command in execute shell, it will once again rerun script.sh and curl command.
I dont want script.sh to be run again because job is success

1. Can I run curl and deploy  final artifacts to Artifactory without starting the build again on the same job?
2. Final jobs are deleted automatically, can I have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try and log on to the agent to see if the job workspace is still there, in which case you can perform the curl from there.

But if the workspace is cleaned up at the end (Post-build Actions / Delete workspace)... you will have to re-run everything (script+curl).

Comment: hi Vonc, thanks for your response. My doubt is in build step in jenkins, i should have used build.sh and curl command one after the another. but what happens is i used only build.sh and forgotten curl. and the build.sh is successfully built and workspace is also there i have not deleted.                                                                                        
 my question here is i want to configure the same job in such a way that i should add curl after build.sh and run the same job in jenkins so that it will not build again and apply curl to the same final artifacts